# R - Construct a data frame with multiple columns without assign

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

My goal is to create a `data frame` with a number `i` of columns named `ColumnName_1` -> `ColumnName_i`

The result would be for `i = 3` :

```
structure(list(ColumnName_1 = c(0, 0, 0), ColumnName_2 = c(0, 
0, 0), ColumnName_3 = c(0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ColumnName_1", 
"ColumnName_2", "ColumnName_3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I understand from other questions on others topics that it's not recommended to use `assign` but it's the only solution that I see at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the following, supposing you want `m` rows and `n` columns:

```
data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = m, ncol = n,
           dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("ColumnName_", 1:n))) )
```

All other answers uses a loop to create columns, while this solution is fully vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that uses `replicate` and `data.frame` to construct an empty data.frame of whatever size you'd like (with numeric variables) and then uses `setNames` to provide variable names.

```
setNames(data.frame(replicate(3, numeric(3), simplify=FALSE)),
         paste0("colName", seq_len(3)))

  colName1 colName2 colName3
1        0        0        0
2        0        0        0
3        0        0        0
```

The first argument to replicate provides the number of columns and the second argument `numeric(3)` provides the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

A version with `lapply`.

```
i <- 3
setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(1:i, function(k) c(0, 0, 0))),
         paste("ColumnName_", 1:i, sep = ""))
```